# Order of argument in both Junit and Hamcrest

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, hamcrest

I saw the following code snippet online:

[image]

As it mentioned, the argument order of Junit(expected, actual) and Hamcrest(actual, expected) is reversed.

I was wondering what is the reason behind it? Does the argument order really matter for Junit or Hamcrest? If someone accidently placed the argument in the wrong order, will it affect the result?

Comment: In case of junit, when testcase would fail, you would get reversed message saying was expecting "abc" and got "pqr" which in reality would be vice versa. but in reality it doesnt makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of that confusion goes away when you realize that you **only** need to use **assertThat**. This assert simply does what all the others do; and it does it in a much better way.

And no, the order doesn't really matter. In the end, this is about matching two values. If the two values are identical, you don't care.

The only problem: if you reverse values, then fixing broken tests might be harder - as you should better understand the difference between the *actual* and the *expected* value.

Finally: there is a simple helper when using assertThat. It wants A (ctual), then E(expected). Very much in alphabetical order.

Comment: i like the 'finally' part

Answer (score 4):

Well, for Hamcrest, the types are actually different: the left-hand side is an `Object` and the right hand side is a `Matcher`.

For JUnit the difference is "only" semantics, i.e. you get a misleading assert message in case of failure.

[AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) (to add another example) uses a fluent-style interface:

```java
assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);
assertThat(actual).isGreaterThan(expected);
...
```